# How to align a div in the center of a HTML page?

Tags: html

I've to align some text in the center of the page with div tag.

Answer (score 5):

```
div#foo { text-align:center; }
```

to align the text within the div or

```
div#foo { width:100px; margin:0 auto; }
```

to make the div 100px width and horizontally center it.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the style of the div to be:

```
<div style="width: 250px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">TEXT</div>
```

You can also place that style in a CSS class and set the class of the div to whatever you named it.

EDIT: If you include a width for the div, it centers...

Comment: @RageZ: My CSS style is exactly like meder's... I just forgot the width.

Comment: That should technically be a `span` not a `div` as it is just used to apply styles to some text.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `<div align="center">...</div>`

Comment: That only centers the text. If OP specifies a width to the <div> then the div will still display blocked to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the following styling:

```
div {margin:0 auto;}
```